# Связь одной модели с несколькими по fk Django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть несколько моделей

```
class Car(models.Model):

class Nootebook(models.Model):

class Food(models.Model):
```

и к каждой из этих моделей я хочу добавлять несколько картинок. Модель для картинок у всех одинаковая.

```
class Image(models.Model):
     image = models.ImageField('Изображение', upload_to=get_image_path)
     desc = models.TextField('описание альбома')
```

Знаю что можно написать 3 таких модели с изображениями и к каждой связь по `FK`.
Но тогда будет повторятся код одинаковый. Как быть в таком случае?
Добавит еще одну промежуточную модель к которой Car, Nootebook, Food будут ссылаться через FK.
Т.е

```
class General_model(model.Models):

class Image(models.Model):
    g_m = models.ForeignKey(General_model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Car(models.Model):
     g_m = models.ForeignKey(General_model,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

или можно поступить как-нибудь по-другому

Comment: в каждый из классов (Car, Nootebook, Food) добавить fk на Image?

Comment: По сути да, вам нужна какая-то промежуточная модель, представляющая серию картинок, только назвать лучше не абстрактно "GeneralModel", а что-то типа `ImageGallery` или `ImageSeries`.

Comment: @Jack_oS, может быть несколько картинок у каждого объекта

Comment: @insolor еще наткнулся на абстрактные модели, вроде это можно тоже использовать в данном случае?

Comment: @Вадим если картинок может быть несколько, то это не поможет. Абстрактные модели просто позволяют вынести из схожих моделей общие поля. Если во всех моделях общее только поле картинки (галереи), то нет особого смысла выносить его в абстрактную модель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем проблемы в классе с изображениями указать

```
class Image(...):
   image = models.ImageField(...)

   product = models.ForeignKey(to=Product, null=True, blank=True, ...)
   category = models.ForeignKey(to=Category, null=True, blank=True, ...)
```

И при перед сохранением проверять, что точно 1 значения из FK не None ?

Можете еще написать свой @register и метод, который генерирует этот класс со связями, на основе базового абстрактного класса

Comment: тогда уже скорее проверять что только одно может быть заполнено. А ChoiceField нельзя никак использовать для Fk?

Comment: Тут подразумевается что Product как раз родительский/абстрактный класс для каждой из моделей?

Comment: @insolor  нет. Image абстрактный. А Реализация уже зависит от того как хочется - куча связей в одной сгенерированной модели или по одной в множестве сгенерированных